# Horizontal slider with jQuery: 100% height, auto width for the images/children

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've been trying to find a solution to my issue for the past few days, but really couldn't find it anywhere, and Google literally hates me, so here I am. This is a big request and my conscience is eating at me for asking, but I don't know where else to turn.

I am building a gallery for a photographer, and while I'm at ease with HTML and CSS, my jQuery skills are taking a beating (in short, they're not good) - surprise, surprise.

The task becomes even more complex since it's a 100% height kind of gallery, and 100% heights don't play nice. I manage to set some of it up, but its functionality is really impaired.

After digging here on Stack and Google I found this great Plugin/Fiddle by William Moynihan:
http://jsfiddle.net/wdm954/8GKz6/11/

It contains **exactly my markup and CSS**, as well as the functionality I was looking for: a slider which centers the main image when sliding, and is infinite.

However, it doesn't play well with `height: 100%;` because of the `width: auto;` property on the images. The following line:

`$(content).width(w * $(section).length);`

Doesn't appear to calculate the width of the container at all (sets it to zero) because of the auto property in the CSS. When I set the width via the jQuery .css property to `('width', 'auto')`, it works fine, but the sliding function is imperfect, causing images to skip/jump when moving right and left.

I didn't resort to a slider, because this is a nice way to actually have the content layed out, in a horizontal manner, which is something that looks great on a photographer's website. And of having `width: 100%;` will make the vertical images stretch past the browser window, and the horizontal ones to "hang" at the top with plenty of white space below. So, I am convinced that `width: auto;` and `height: 100%` is the correct, responsive way to go about it, but if someone manages to "unconvince" me, I will definitely follow your lead.

*While I'm here, maybe someone could be polite enough to point me in the right direction to make this gallery finite - ending at the start and end of the slider, with the left/right buttons disappearing accordingly.*

Any help is greatly appreciated. Here is the code itself, just in case the fiddle isn't enough:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="gallery">
        <img src="../img/1.jpg" alt="Image" />
        <img src="../img/2.jpg" alt="Image" />
        <img src="../img/3.jpg" alt="Image" />
        <img src="../img/4.jpg" alt="Image" />
        <img src="../img/5.jpg" alt="Image" />
    </div>
</div>
<nav id="navigation">
    <a href="#" class="left">&#060;&#060;</a>
    <a href="#" class="right">&#062;&#062;</a>
</nav>

<script>
/*  jQuery Ghost Carousel
 *  Copyright (c) 2011 William Moynihan
 *  http://ghosttype.com
 *  Licensed under MIT
 *  http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php
 *  May 31, 2011 -- v1.0
 */
$(function() {
    var content = '.container .gallery';
    var section = content + ' > img';

    function ghostCarousel() {

        var v = $(window).width();
        var w = $(section).width();
        var c = (w * $(section).length - v) / 2;

        $(content).width(w * $(section).length);
        $(content).css('margin-left', -c);
        $(content).css('width','auto');

        $('#navigation a.left').click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            if ($(content).is(':animated')) return false;
            $(content).animate({ marginLeft: '-=' +w }, 1000, function() {
                var first = $(section).eq(0);
                $(section).eq(0).remove();
                $(this).animate({ marginLeft: '+=' +w }, 0);
                $(this).append(first);
            });
        });
        $('#navigation a.right').click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            if ($(content).is(':animated')) return false;
            $(content).animate({ marginLeft: '+=' +w }, 1000, function() {
                var end = $(section).length - 1;
                var last = $(section).eq(end);
                $(section).eq(end).remove();
                $(this).animate({ marginLeft: '-=' +w }, 0);
                $(this).prepend(last);
            });
        });

    }

    ghostCarousel();

    $(window).resize(function() {
        var v = $(window).width();
        var w = $(section).width();
        var c = (w * $(section).length - v) / 2;
        $(content).css('margin-left', -c);
    });   
});
/* end "jQuery Ghost Carousel" */
</script>
```

Along with the CSS:

```
html, body { padding: 0px; }

.container {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;   
}
.container .gallery > img {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Ok, I'm going to have a look into this height issue. The finite functionality and dynamic buttons shouldn't be too hard to implement but for now could you provide me with the sizes for the images you want to be using in the gallery? Also, if you can put the 5 sample images online somewhere then you can just reference them directly in the jsfiddle demo.

Comment: I agree with @Ambrosia: I'm not sure I see the issue on fiddle, and need images to be more helpful. Create an account on imgur, load some images there, then call them in your fiddle.

Comment: I don't want to give the as an answer but this might help you if you're stuck with this. I use carouFredsel for all my slider/carousel needs. I've very easy to use even if you jquery is rusty and has tons of example to 'get ideas' from like this one: http://coolcarousels.frebsite.nl/c/31/ or even this one http://coolcarousels.frebsite.nl/c/2/. It has a handy generator for the code. Anyway, it might save you a lot of trouble. check it out at: http://caroufredsel.dev7studios.com/

Comment: Wow. It's been more than two months, and I truly wasn't expecting anyone to answer. The issue was more or less resolved, but not in a way I'm pleased with, so here goes, just in case...

@Ambrosia, that's the thing, I am dealing with auto width, because the uploads are dynamic (Wordpress), and both vertical and horizontal images are in play. Do the dimensions really matter in that case?

Comment: @TravisHeeter,
Here an example of what I did, but the problem kind of persists, since the container doesn't seem to calculate the image width properly, so it either skips two or three of the last images on big resolutions (i.e. 1920x1080), or it creates a huge black gap at the end on smaller ones (I used the Sly plugin, since the above code didn't seem to work for me at all).

http://olgapalet.com/beautiful-people/

Just in case, the Sly plugin:
http://darsa.in/sly/

Answer (score 1):

To make it finite, you need to understand and modify this tow functions only,

```
        $('#gcNav a.left').click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            if ($(content).is(':animated')) return false;
            $(content).animate({ marginLeft: '-=' +w }, 1000, function() {
                var first = $(section).eq(0);//this is first
                $(section).eq(0).remove();
                $(this).animate({ marginLeft: '+=' +w }, 0);
                $(this).append(first);//adding
            });
        });
        $('#gcNav a.right').click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            if ($(content).is(':animated')) return false;
            $(content).animate({ marginLeft: '+=' +w }, 1000, function() {
                var end = $(section).length - 1;
                var last = $(section).eq(end);//this is last
                $(section).eq(end).remove();
                $(this).animate({ marginLeft: '-=' +w }, 0);
                $(this).prepend(last);//adding
            });
        });
```

Now, in this code, it is working with click on .left, and .right, if you want to make it finite,

just calculate the length of slides, and stop adding the slides, I have added the comments..

I have just pointed out the way...

I hope this will help...

Comment: it has been more than two months, and I didn't think anyone would answer my question, but yours seems to be the solution I was looking for (I found one that works, but it's not perfect). I will try it and get back to you.